# Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected (JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

i'm new to oracle and java. I'm trying to understand why my code isn't working. Each time when i execute the last bit of code, i get that error. I've been trying to understand why i get it for quite some time, but i can't solve it. There's only one SELECT statement in this code. I think there aren't any mistakes there. 
Code from WageK.java:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class wage
{
public static void getWage
(int wage_id, java.lang.String[] w_name, java.lang.String[] w_lname, 
int[] w_wage, int[] w_month, int[] wage_calc)
throws SQLException 
{
try
{
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  String sql = "Select name, last_name, wage, 
  n_month, Value(A).wage_calc() as your_wage" +"From wage_java A" + 
  "Where A.ID = ?";

  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pstmt.setInt(1, wage_id);
  rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

  if (rs.next()) 
  {
    w_name[0] = rs.getString("name");
    w_lname[0] = rs.getString("last_name");
    w_wage[0] = rs.getInt("wage");
    w_month[0] = rs.getInt("n_month");
    wage_calc[0] = rs.getInt("wage_calc");
  }
  else
  {
    w_name[0] = "0";
    w_lname[0] = "0";
    w_wage[0] = 0;
    w_month[0] = 0;
    wage_calc[0] = 0;       
  }
   }
   catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
 }
}
```

Then i was publishing the PL/SQL wrapper using this code.

```
Create or replace procedure getWage (wage_id IN NUMBER, w_name OUT VARCHAR2, 
w_lname OUT VARCHAR2, w_wage OUT NUMBER, w_month OUT NUMBER, 
wage_calc OUT NUMBER) AS language Java name 'WageK.getWage
(int, java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],int[], int[], int[])';
```

But when i try to access it using this code, it gives me that error:

```
set serveroutput ON;
call  DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(2000);

declare
  w_name VARCHAR2(20);
  w_lname VARCHAR2(20);
  w_wage Number;
  w_month Number;
  wage_calc Number;

BEGIN
  getWage(1, w_name, w_lname, w_wage, w_month, wage_calc);
  dbms_output.Put_line('Wages of employee's:');
  dbms_output.Put_line('  ' || wage_calc);
end;
```

Any help regarding my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print out the string after it is created.  At least some of the problems would be obvious, such as:

```
Select name, last_name, wage, 
  n_month, Value(A).wage_calc() as your_wageFrom wage_java AWhere A.ID = ?;
```

In other words, you need spaces in the string, something like this:

```
String sql = "Select name, last_name, wage, n_month, Value(A).wage_calc() as your_wage " +
             "From wage_java A " + 
             "Where A.ID = ?";
```

Comment: Indeed, that helped to get rid of that error, but now i have a new one - "Invalid column name". I fixed this line of code too: dbms_output.Put_line('Wages of employee's:'); Do you know where is my mistake? @Gordon

Comment: Thanks. You save my life.